# CodeIgniter: Proxy Check and Block

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am having this difficulties in handling request because certain of my web application users used proxy to access, and seeing this as unnecessary and might be the cause of data leaks, is there any solutions or already built in CI Framework to block the and check the proxy as well as the IP(s)?

Comment: You will need to subscribe to IP geolocation service or anonymous proxy blacklist to perform the detection.

Comment: Is this mean that I cannot detect this using code? because I did found some web used this kind of methods.